# Smooth Scroll on selection change jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to scroll to the anchor smoothly on dropdown selection change. Tried a lot of code from other answers but couldnt get it to work since i have no experience with jquery. 
Any help would be appreciated!
P.S : dont mind the link selector if statements

here is my dropdown

```
<select class="form-control " id="dropDownSelect" onchange="location = this.value;">
                                    <option value="#">Hotel Selection</option>
                                    <option value="#ecoHotel">EcoName</option>
                                    <option value="#luxuryHotel">LuxuryName</option>
                                </select>
```

and here is the jquery i am trying to implement in

```
<script>


    $("#dropDownSelect").change(function() {
        console.log(this.value);

        // Here Should be my smoothscroll       

        if (this.value === "#luxuryHotel") {
            $("#inqLink").attr('href', "http://www.google.com");
        }
        else{
            $("#inqLink").attr('href', "package-dentmodern-hollywoodsmile-inquire.html");
        }


    });




</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got another solution for you. Make your own `dropdown`, in this way it is more easy for you to achieve what you want. I did all the drop down functions with `JQuery`, you just have to style dropdown:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.target-click').click(function(){
   $('.hidden-drop').slideToggle();
  })
      $('nav  li a').click(function(e) {
      setTimeout(function(){
         $('.hidden-drop').slideUp();
      }, 200);
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 600);
    return false;
  });
  });
```

```css
select {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#ecoHotel {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
#luxuryHotel {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.page {
    display: block;
  height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
.hidden-drop {
  display: none;
}
ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
}
ul {
padding: 0;  
}
span.target-click {
  color: #444;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    height: 44px;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 44px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

  <nav>
    <ul> 
     <li>
     <span class="target-click">Hotel Selection</span>  
     <ul class="hidden-drop">
       <li><a href="#ecoHotel">EcoName</a></li>
       <li><a href="#luxuryHotel">LuxuryName</a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
</nav>
                                
 <div id="ecoHotel" class="page">Eco Hotel Section</div>
 <div id="luxuryHotel" class="page">Luxury Hotel Section</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but unfortunately I am not flexible with the design.
by the way, was it you who chat with my teammate on the website? :)

Comment: Yes, I thought you will not see the answer. I thought this would help. All the best! :)

Comment: No I am on top of this :) But so far i will have to skip this step and come back to it later.

Comment: Was it you again who left a comment on my website? Cos it solved my problem and I will mark as an answer if you edit your answer. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @firativerson, I'm so happy to hear that! All the best! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#target').offset().top
}, 1000);
```

This will scroll smoothly to the DOM element with the targeted `id`

`1000` is in miliseconds.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i keep getting this error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined.

Website is live here if you want to try
http://www.mediroute.com/package-dentmodern-hollywoodsmile_dd.html

Comment: Thats probaly because you gave the target a non existing target id or class. Search for the ID or class where you want to page to scroll to. In my example the page will scroll to the id #target. However, i checked your link and i think you allready figured out ;)

Comment: No I didnt, It doesnt smooth scroll. I am a sucker at js and jquery so any further help will be appreciated.